# Using resources across classes?

Tags: java, android, caching

I have a GameLoop class with a ParticleSystem object defined in it.

The ParticleSystem contains an array of Particle objects - I don't want to have to load an image for each individual particle, id like to just be able to draw from a source image in the GameLoop class - how can I do this in an efficient manner?

**SOLUTION:**

Here is what Dan S helped me come up with:

```
public class ResourceManager  {

Context mContext;   

public final HashMap<String, Bitmap> Texture = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

//Constructor
public ResourceManager(Context context)
{       
    mContext = context;
    Texture.put("particle1", loadBitmap(R.drawable.particle1));
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(String key)
{   
return Texture.get(key);
}

 /** Load an image */
    protected Bitmap loadBitmap(int id) { return   BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), id); }

  } //End ResourceManager
```

then define it in a class:

```
rm = new ResourceManager(mContext);
```

And then pass the rm variable down the way:

```
    ParticleSystem.Draw(rm, canvas);
   {
     Particle.Draw(rm, canvas);
    }
```

and in Particle class, there is a String assetKey I set in constructor - so that I can refer to the Bitmap by a name:

```
public void doDraw(ResourceManager rm, Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(rm.getBitmap(AssetKey), xpos, ypos, null);
}
```

I hope this is helpful to someone else also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor of GameLoop create your bitmaps and hold a reference to them there, set them as final variables for added protection against accidental assignment.  Whenever you create a new particle system pass them to the constructor or set them in an appropriate setter method.

**Example:**

```
// in GameLoop definition

private Bitmap particleA;
private Bitmap particleB;

// somewhere in GameLoop constructor
particleA = BitmapFactor.decodeResource (activity.getResources(), R.drawable.particle_a);
particleB = BitmapFactor.decodeResource (activity.getResources(), R.drawable.particle_b);

// where you build your particle
Particle (GameLoop gl, ...) {
   oneLevelDown = new OneLevelDown(GameLoop gl, ...);
}

OneLevelDown (GameLoop gl, ...) {
   twoLevelDown = new TwoLevelDown(GameLoop gl, ...);
}

TwoLevelDown (GameLoop gl, ...) {
   particleABitmap = gl.getParticleA(); // simple getter
   particleBBitmap = gl.getParticleB(); // simple getter
}
```

Just keep passing GameLoop down until you're done. This might not feel efficient but once you get the hang of it you'll like, also see this article about [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Java memory usage example:

```
class Car{
   public int year;
   public int name;
}

// Object variables are references to an object's data.

Car a = new Car(); // first car object and variable. 
a.year = 1990;
a.name = "Sam";

Car b = new Car();// second car object and variable
b.year = 2000;
b.name = "Bob";

Car c = a; // third car **variable** but same car object as **a**

// primitives are different

int a = 23; // first variable, 4 bytes used
int b = 45; // second variable, 4 bytes used (and a total of 8)
int c = a;  // third variable, 4 bytes used (and a total of 12). c took on the value of a, but does not point to the same memory as a
```

Comment: I have been trying to implement something similar, unfortunatly the difficulty comes in reaching the GameLoop when a new Particle is created.

How would I access a variable in GameLoop from 2 classes below:

Particle[0] = new Particle(GameLoop.Bitmap);

Comment: Just pass the GameLoop object down as far as you need to. This is similar to how Context is passed to View objects for creation.

Comment: could you give me a snippet of how you'de "call" the GameLoop class from Particle?

Are you saying to create a new Object in the Particle Class?
Like: Resources = new ResourceClass(); Bitmap test = Resources.Bitmap -- if I do that am I not just creating a duplicate of every single bitmap in the ResourceClass definition? I'm hoping to define it once and then use it in another class

Comment: Check out my edit. Object assignment in Java does not duplicate the object, just the value of the object id which the JVM uses to reference the real data. The only duplication is the JVM object reference size, usually 32-bit on 32-bit processors.  The exception to this are immutable objects such as String but that is only if the method called changes the internal state.

Comment: Ok, so it was inistantiating a new version of the object on each level down -- forgive my ignorance, but doesn't this create a duplicate of every single bitmap, every single time I create a new particle?...Is their a gap in my knowledge about how creating a new class works? BTW, I appreciate you not just posting a link to Java.com and telling me to learn everything everywhere ever.

Comment: The Bitmap is not duplicated, only the reference to the object is. Similar to a pointer but don't think of it that way.

Comment: I guess I was wrong about what happens when a new class is created - I thought every variable in the class was duplicated - class Car() { int Year=2001; } ~~~~ theCar = new Car(); int WhichYear = theCar.Year -- if I create the class "theCar" and then change the year, the class definition isn't changed? Doesn't that mean that they are two seperate variables?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quite understand what your trying to say - when you said it would just reference the variable it's like being told the Sky is red - I looked up the documentation on classes and it said "every object constructed from the class definition will have its own copy of the field. " http://java.sun.com/docs/white/langenv/Object.doc2.html   --section 3.3.1, doesn't that mean that creating an object out of a class just creates a physical copy of it?

Comment: Yes, but remember **new** creates, **=** assigns.

Comment: OMG. so just referencing the object in the constructor and then using the variables while it's a local will work?!

Comment: So the best implementation of the Particle Draw() method would be something like: public void Draw(AllResources ar, Canvas c, Paint p) { c.drawBitmap(ar.GetParticleImage(), Position.x, Position.y, p); Would I even need to create an AllResources object on GameLoop?

Comment: That depends, how often the bitmap changes in your Particle, if it changes often, pass the resources, if its set once or just updated a "few" times then put it in the constructor.

Comment: thx so much ~ I have asked this question on just about every forum from time to time whether it be Direct X or XNA or Java - I used interfaces in XNA and I barely understood what was happenning but they worked, this might not be the prettiest way but it sure is the most straight forward and workable -- so now as far as I can tell all I rly have to do is add an "int assetID" in the particle object and then grab the bitmap at Draw like: c.DrawBitmap(AllResources.getBitmap(assetID), ..., ...);

Comment: Yep - totally worked - my particle system, which was once composed of 100 objects and therefore 100 bitmaps are now drawing all their gfx's from 2 bitmaps ~ I'm new here so I'm not sure how to share my solution - should I answer my own question but check this post as the Answer?

Comment: You can post your own answer, but when you upvote or check an answer be sure it relates to the original question.  Also try to make some time to master the details of the language you're using, you'll be able to move even faster through your projects without guessing what's going on.